# Re-Evaluate value of constant FieldExpression on each invoke

Tags: c#, .net, expression

### Setup

I've got a method that I want to invoke periodically. The method has two DateTime parameter.

```
public static object PrintDateTimes(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
{
    Console.WriteLine(
        string.Format("PrintDateTimes:\t{0} - {1} :: {2}", fromDate.ToLongTimeString(), toDate.ToLongTimeString(), Program.StartDateTimeString));
    return 0;
}
```

The class `Item` provides the method `Refresh` and the property `callback` to store a method that's supposed to be invoked.

```
public class Item
{
    public Expression<Func<object>> callback { get; set;  }
    
    public void Refresh()
    {
        this.Refresh(this.callback);
    }

    public void Refresh(Expression<Func<object>> callback)
    {
        MethodCallExpression methodBody = (MethodCallExpression)callback.Body;
        bool fromDateFound = false;
        bool toDateFound = false;

        foreach (var arg in methodBody.Arguments) {

            if (arg.Type == typeof(DateTime)) {

                if (fromDateFound && !toDateFound) {
                    
                    DateTime fromDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Expression.Lambda(arg).Compile().DynamicInvoke());

                    Console.WriteLine("newFromDate\t" + fromDate);
                    
                    toDateFound = true;

                } else if (!fromDateFound) {

                    DateTime toDate = Convert.ToDateTime(Expression.Lambda(arg).Compile().DynamicInvoke());

                    fromDateFound = true;

                    Console.WriteLine("newToDate\t" + toDate);
                }
            }
        }

        callback.Compile().Invoke();

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

The main method looks like this

```
public static string StartDateTimeString;

public static void Main()
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-0.5);
    DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

    Program.StartDateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    Item item = new Item();

    // this is important
    AssignCallback(fromDate, toDate, item);

    timer = new Timer(timerCallback, item, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

    timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
    while (true) ;
}

public static void AssignCallback(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, Item item)
{
    item.callback = () => Program.PrintDateTimes(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

and finally the timer callback

```
private static void timerCallback(object state)
{
    Item i = state as Item;

    i.Refresh();

    Console.WriteLine("Refresh at:\t" + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

    timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
}
```

### Problem

This is the output when executing the code (and waiting for a few seconds)

```
Refresh at:     10:53:58
newToDate       10:23:58
newFromDate     11:53:58
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:58 - 11:53:58 :: 10:53:58

Refresh at:     10:54:01
newToDate       10:23:58
newFromDate     11:53:58
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:58 - 11:53:58 :: 10:53:58

Refresh at:     10:54:04
newToDate       10:23:58
newFromDate     11:53:58
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:58 - 11:53:58 :: 10:53:58

Refresh at:     10:54:07
newToDate       10:23:58
newFromDate     11:53:58
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:58 - 11:53:58 :: 10:53:58
```

So far so good, however that's not the desired output.
When invoking the callback, the DateTime values of the initial call will be used - but I want them to be evaluated again on every invoke, not just passed with their old value.

The desired output would be this (note the seconds)

```
Refresh at:     10:53:58
newToDate       10:23:58
newFromDate     11:53:58
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:58 - 11:53:58 :: 10:53:58

Refresh at:     10:54:01
newToDate       10:23:01
newFromDate     11:53:01
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:01 - 11:53:01 :: 10:53:58

Refresh at:     10:54:04
newToDate       10:23:04
newFromDate     11:53:04
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:04 - 11:53:04 :: 10:53:58

Refresh at:     10:54:07
newToDate       10:23:07
newFromDate     11:53:07
PrintDateTimes: 10:23:07 - 11:53:07 :: 10:53:58
```

### What I've figured out

I've noticed that the type of `arg` in `foreach (var arg in methodBody.Arguments) {` is a `FieldExpression` which - afaik - means it's constant.

If I remove the call to `AssignCallback` and assign the callback directly, so `item.callback = () => PrintDateTimes(DateTime.Now.AddHours(-0.5), DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));` it actually works.

Probably because then `arg` will be of the type `InstanceMethodCallExpressionN`, so no constant. Seems like the will be evaluated on each invoke rather than being passsed with a constant value.

### Question

Is there a way to re-evaluate those parameter on each call, so that the values will be updated correctly?

Comment: Why are you using `Expression<Func<>>` instead of just `Func<>`?

Comment: I had to adjust the ```DateTime``` parameter manually instead of just passing them. But even with a ```Func<>``` this remains the same, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If i follow your example correctly, your `Refresh` method doesn't seem to update the values - it picks whatever expression you assigned to it and reevaluates it over and over.

So what it seems you are missing is the actual update to `fromDate, toDate` in your `timerCallback`. I assume you have reasons to use an expression there, but if not - a simple delegate might actually do the job with a bit less code (and performance penalty):

```
public class Item
{
    public Func<DateTime, DateTime, object> callbackFunc { get; set; } // to illustrate alternative point
    public Expression<Func<object>> callback { get; set; }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        Refresh(callback);
    }

    public void RefreshFunc(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate) // alternative execution path - see timerCallback()
    {
        callbackFunc(fromDate, toDate);
    }
    

    public void Refresh(Expression<Func<object>> callback)
    {
        //your code with no change where
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static object PrintDateTimes(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"PrintDateTimes:\t{fromDate.ToLongTimeString()} - {toDate.ToLongTimeString()} :: {Program.StartDateTimeString}");
        return 0;
    }

    public static string StartDateTimeString;
    private static Timer timer;

    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime fromDate = now.AddHours(-0.5);
        DateTime toDate = now.AddHours(1);

        Program.StartDateTimeString = now.ToLongTimeString();

        Item item = new Item();

        // this is important
        AssignCallback(fromDate, toDate, item);

        timer = new Timer(timerCallback, item, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

        timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
        while (true) ;
    }

    public static void AssignCallback(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, Item item)
    {
        item.callback = () => Program.PrintDateTimes(fromDate, toDate);
    }
    private static void timerCallback(object state)
    {
        Item i = state as Item;
        // update the dates
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime fromDate = now.AddHours(-0.5);
        DateTime toDate = now.AddHours(1);
        // call refresh delegate - you proably don't even need to wrap it in a method: i.callbackFunc(toDate, fromDate)
        i.RefreshFunc(fromDate, toDate);

        // or use your old method, but update the expression so it gets new values
        //AssignCallback(fromDate, toDate, i); // i'm not sure if you can do this in your actual code, but this basically reassigns the expression so it works
        //i.Refresh();

        Console.WriteLine("Refresh at:\t" + now.ToLongTimeString());

        timer.Change(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, the problem is that I don't know the values of the parameter, so I can't update them. The ```DateTime.Now.AddHours(-0.5)``` and ```DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)``` are just examples.

Comment: so where are the values coming from?

Comment: That's a library, so ```callback``` could be anything the programmer decides to use

Comment: Then you might want to consider my `Func<DateTime,DateTime,Object>` suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
public static void AssignCallback(DateTime fromDate, DateTime toDate, Item item)
{
    item.callback = () => Program.PrintDateTimes(fromDate, toDate);
}
```

Local variables are captured inside lambda, which means they are promoted by compiler to fields of some compiler-generated class. That's why you have `FieldExpression`, and it's not constant. However, you do not update those (field-promoted) variables `fromDate` and `toDate` anywhere, so their value stays constant between executions indeed.

If you remove `AssignCallback` and do the same directly inside main:

```
item.callback = () => Program.PrintDateTimes(fromDate, toDate);
```

Then it's still `FieldExpression`, but you can update `fromDate` and `toDate`, and this change will be reflected. For example:

```
while (true) {
    Console.ReadKey();
    fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-0.5);
    toDate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
}
```

Then each time you press the button in console - local (captured) variables will be updated, and next invocation of your callback will reflect that.

There is no other way to "refresh" those dates if you pass them directly as `DateTime`. You cannot know it was initialized as `DateTime.Now.AddHours(-0.5)`, all you have is (already calculated) `DateTime` value. In your case it's better to make it explicit that your callback expects not `DateTime` value, but a way to get such value. For example:

```
public static void AssignCallback(Func<DateTime> fromDate, Func<DateTime> toDate, Item item) {
    item.callback = () => Program.PrintDateTimes(fromDate(), toDate());
}
```

And then:

```
public static void Main() {
    Func<DateTime> fromDate = () => DateTime.Now.AddHours(-0.5);
    Func<DateTime> toDate = () => DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);

    Program.StartDateTimeString = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

    Item item = new Item();

    // this is important
    AssignCallback(fromDate, toDate, item);

    timer = new Timer(timerCallback, item, Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);

    timer.Change(0, Timeout.Infinite);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Then it's quite clear what's going on at least.

Comment: Thanks for your response, the approach with passing them as a ```Func<DateTime>``` looks promising, I totally didn't think of that. I'll try that and get back later.